# pdf to jpg using ImageMagick generate additional empty file

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, imagick

When I convert pdf to jpg I allways get one jpg file which is empty. How to avoid it? 

This is my query:
`convert some.pdf -resize 800x600 -background white -gravity center -extent 800x600 -fill white xc:white -unsharp 0x1 some.jpg`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
convert some.pdf -resize 800x600 -background white -gravity center -extent 800x600 -unsharp 0x1 some.jpg
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Especially because I need white background. Does anyone have other ideas?